# Connecting sagemaker using java sdk

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Can anyone tell me how to connect to sagemaker using aws java sdk and invoke a endpoint which is arleady created using jupyter notebook?

Link -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemaker/AmazonSageMaker.html#createNotebookInstance-com.amazonaws.services.sagemaker.model.CreateNotebookInstanceRequest-

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder.html) to create a client and then use that client to call [invokeEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/AmazonSageMakerRuntime.html#invokeEndpoint-com.amazonaws.services.sagemakerruntime.model.InvokeEndpointRequest-).

At a minimum, your [InvokeEndpointRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html) will need to have the [endpointName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html#setEndpointName-java.lang.String-) and [body](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html#setBody-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) set, but you should also specify the [contentType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-) and [accept](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html#setAccept-java.lang.String-), as many models require that information.